# Emulating shader results using FFMPEG filters

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, glsl

I’m developing a video editor for android.Using SurfaceView, I process video frames by superimposing a shader on them. This is used to preview the filter effect. In the present I will apply a filter through FFMPEG.

For example, such a shader:

https://www.geeks3d.com/20110408/cross-stitching-post-processing-shader-glsl-filter-geexlab-pixel-bender/

[Filter Overlay Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyGhx.png)

But how to repeat the filter effect using FFMPEG?